# How can i change the fbwebdialogs title?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-app-requests, facebook-sdk-3.1, facebook-invite

If i go straight to the point then please help me how can i change the title of the FBWebdialogs of facebook invite friend request.i am using Facebook SDK 3.12 .

[image]

Is it possible to change or any limitations ?
If possible then please suggest me how can i do that.

so far i have done this

```
 [FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"This is my message!"
 title:@"My title"
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
```

but still its not working. please help me.

Regards
Emon